# Как использовать переменную, которой пользователь присваивает значение в другом методе/процедуре?

Tags: c#, методы, переменные, процедуры

Есть проблема, суть такова:

По задумке пользователь должен присваивать значение переменной, а переменная должна использоваться в процедуре, не могу понять как это реализовать

Вот код:

```
using System;
namespace Zimin_Laba6___
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали программу 3");
            Console.WriteLine("...Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...");
            try
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Дана Задача:");
                Console.WriteLine("Составьте процедуру, которая выводит на экран количество чисел, кратных 3, \nбольших 0 и меньших N. Значение числа N передавать процедуре в качестве обязательного параметра.");
                Console.WriteLine("Решение:");
                Console.WriteLine("Введите N, оно будет передано в процедуру*");
                double N = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Zadanie3();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR вы ввели данные в неправильном формате, пожалуйста попробуйте снова ;)");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR вы ввели данные в неправильном формате, пожалуйста попробуйте снова ;)");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("...Для завершения программы, нажмите ENTER...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    static void Zadanie3(double N)
    {
        double d = 0;
        for (double c = 3; c < N; c++)
        {
            if (c % 3 == 0)
            {
                d++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Чисел кратных 3 (при этом больше нуля и меньше " + N + ") = " +d);
    }
}
```

Желательно понятным языком ибо я новичок, заранее спасибо)

Comment: По сути эта программа должна выдавать ошибку и не запускаться. У вас метод Zadanie3 принимает в себя параметр N. Просто так вызвать Zadanie3() не правильно. В него обязательно нужно передать параметр. Он у вас определяется выше из консоли. По сути необходимо переделать вызов Zadanie3() в методе Main на Zadanie3(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   Zadanie3(N);

 ...

static void Zadanie3(int N)
{
    int d = (N - 1) / 3;
    Console.WriteLine("Чисел кратных 3 (при этом больше нуля и меньше " + N + ") = " +d);
}
```